# Wayland not available after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, wayland, gnome-session

I cannot choose wayland in the login screen, can it be a driver problem?

```
lspci -v 


01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235/310 OEM] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Radeon HD 7470
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f6020000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon

lsmod |grep radeon
radeon               1470464  33
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
ttm                    94208  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 radeon
drm                   356352  13 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper

dpkg --get-selections |grep wayla
gnome-session-wayland               install
kwayland-data                   install
kwayland-integration:amd64          install
libkf5waylandclient5:amd64          install
libqt5waylandclient5:amd64          install
libqt5waylandcompositor5:amd64          install
libva-wayland1:amd64                install
libwayland-bin                  install
libwayland-client0:amd64            install
libwayland-cursor0:amd64            install
libwayland-dev:amd64                install
libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64          install
libwayland-server0:amd64            install
qtwayland5:amd64                install
xwayland                    install
```